WebDriver Issue - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = None


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--browser_name", action="store", default="chrome"
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def setup(request):
    global driver
    # chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    service_obj = Service("/Users/ibrahim/SeleniumProjects/BrowserDrivers/chromedriver")
    # Chrome driver service
    browser_name = request.config.getoption("browser_name")

    if browser_name == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj)  # Initialize chrome driver class
    elif browser_name == "safari":
        driver = webdriver.Safari()
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver

    yield 
    driver.close()


@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    """
        Extends the PyTest Plugin to take and embed screenshot in html report, whenever test fails.
        :param item:
        """
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])

    if report.when == 'call' or report.when == "setup":
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            file_name = report.nodeid.replace("::", "_") + ".png"
            _capture_screenshot(file_name)
            if file_name:
                html = '<div><img src="%s" alt="screenshot" style="width:304px;height:228px;" ' \
                       'onclick="window.open(this.src)" align="right"/></div>' % file_name
                extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html(html))
        report.extra = extra


def _capture_screenshot(name):
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(name)

This is the code in my conftest file. I initialized the driver to none and called globally in setup() and under the setup fixture. I have custom reports code (it captures the screenshot, when the test fails). I am using the driver object to capture the screenshot, but I was not able to run the test because of this:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_screenshot_as_file' error.

The error message is telling you that the variable driver is equal to None. So you need to use the debugger to find out why it has not been initialised.

It works when the 'service=service_obj' parameter is removed. The issue may be related to the local driver or the driver path.

@volkan I first tried without using service_obj. I even updated my chromedriver version to latest which was the cause for many others but didn't work for me.

Based on your comment, you can follow below steps:
1- Verify that you have latest;
Selenium Version: 4.22.0
Chrome Version: 126.0.6478.126/127
2- (Optional) Consider removing report.when == 'setup' unless you intend for that part of the code to be executed twice, given that report.when == 'call' seems more appropriate for your situation
3- Delete 'service_obj'
4- (Optional) Add error handling for unexpected browser name
5- (Optional) Update 'pytest_runtest_makereport' function for deprecated 'report.extra' and '@pytest.mark.hookwrapper'.
Below code covers items 2, 3, 4 and 5 and is expected to work.
(I am using Python version 3.12.4, pytest version 8.2.2, and pytest-html version 4.1.1)
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


driver = None


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--browser_name", action="store", default="chrome"
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope="class", autouse=True)
def setup(request):
    global driver
    browser_name = request.config.getoption("browser_name")

    if browser_name == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    elif browser_name == "safari":
        driver = webdriver.Safari()
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    else:
        raise pytest.UsageError("--browser_name should be chrome, safari, or firefox")

    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver

    yield 
    
    driver.close()


@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    """
    Extends the PyTest Plugin to take and embed screenshot in html report, whenever test fails.
    :param item:
    """
   
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])

    if report.when == 'call':
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            file_name = report.nodeid.replace("::", "_") + ".png"
            _capture_screenshot(file_name)
            if file_name:
                html = '<div><img src="%s" alt="screenshot" style="width:304px;height:228px;" ' \
                       'onclick="window.open(this.src)" align="right"/></div>' % file_name
                extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html(html))
        report.extras = extra


def _capture_screenshot(name):
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(name)
 


Thanks, I used your code and tried, now I am seeing another error
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extras'
previously it said 'get_screenshot_as_file'.
Sorry for the asking more questions, I am new to pytest and selenium.

Do you have pytest-html installed. If not you should have it via pip.
pip3 install pytest-html

Thanks @volkan. Adding pytest-html fixed the issue. Really appreciate your help.
